# ReactJS CSSTransitionGroup on Android browser

Tags: android, css, reactjs

My ReactJS CSSTransitionGroups are failing on Android v4.2. I'll to try to isolate the problem and post an example.

Has anyone run into this before? It looks as if Android does support CSS transitions, so I'm guessing the problem may be in how the CSSTransitionGroup is detecting the `transitionend` event?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug that's been fixed on the master branch of React:

[cc56629: Fix transition end detection for Android](https://github.com/facebook/react/commit/cc56629620bf6929f7bb7d375f3738527eb26031)

It didn't make it into 0.10 but will be in the next release.